# VBA highlighting duplicates in a column

Tags: vba, duplicates

I have a column of excel data which I am trying to highlight duplicate values. When I run the VBA code it highlights every value(and I know some values are only listed once). My data goes from row 4 to row 45605 in column b for reference. Here is the code:

```
Sub sbHighlightDuplicatesInColumn()

    Dim lastRow As Range
    Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    
    
    'makes sure to select the correct sheet to work in
Sheets("repeat offenders").Select

'defines the last row
    'lastRow = Cells(45605, 2)


For iCntr = 4 To 45605
    If Cells(iCntr, 2) <> "" Then
        matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 2), Range("B4:B45605"), 0)
        If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
        Cells(iCntr, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
        End If
Next iCntr
      
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option on the Home tab in the styles section called conditional formatting. You can select the cells you want to apply this to and click  Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cells Rules > Duplicate Values. A dialog will pop up allowing you to change highlight color and some other options. Hope that helps. If you still want to use this way though, you’ll have to add 3 to matchFoundIndex in your second if statement. That makes it work partially but you’ll also need to exclude the currently selected cell from the match function. Match starts from the top row and so the first instance of every duplicate doesn’t get highlighted.

Comment: @Meg If this works for you please hit the check mark to accept the answer.